# mobileadmin with exchange 2003

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, iphone, windows-mobile

We have several users connected to our exchange server using activesync using a variety of devices.  The documentation for mobileadmin appears to indicate that the app should provide a list of active devices somewhere, but i cant seem to find it.  Is there a config change i need to make, or are the docs inaccurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think are misreading it.  you get:

View a list of all devices that are being used **by any enterprise user**

Select/De-select devices to be remotely erased

View the status of pending remote erase requests for each device

View a transaction log that indicates which administrators have issued remote erase commands, in addition to the devices those commands pertained to

Comment: thats probably correct, since thats the functionality thats there now.  it seems easily read to mean a list of all devices though.